# Путь сайта PHP

Tags: php

Как сделать другой путь сайта? К примеру человек с id=1 переходит на свою страницу page.php 
Тогда в строке будет написано http://..../page.php, а как сделать, чтобы было написано http://..../id=1

Comment: чуствую тсу mod rewrite нужен, посмотри в гугле

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать файл в папке `/page/index.php`, в `page.php` добавить строчку:

```
header('location: /page/?id='.$id);//где $id нужный вам идентификатор
```

Тогда в файле `/page/index.php` можно спокойно обработать переменную `$_REQUEST['id']`.
Но смею оговорится, всё это попахивает извращениями, объясните свою проблему конкретней, и тогда получите более грамотный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял - вам необходимы ЧПУ?
тогда apache **mod_rewrite** в помощь...

*файл .htaccess* именно по вашему примеру:

```
RewriteEngine=On #Включаем mod_rewrite
RewriteRule ^page/id([0-9]+)$ /page.php?id=$1 #Собвственно mode_rewrite в действии
```

регулярка слева парсит URL введенный пользователем и ложит значение в $1
вторая же обращается к php скрипту page.php и передает параметр $_GET['id']

Если я вас правильно понял то вот как-то так. Хотел добавить - правило сработает только тогда когда после id будет введено числовое значение, что тоже довольно таки удобно.